# Painting QPolygonF on a scene manually causes rendering issues when updating

Tags: c++, qt

I have a quite simple code for painting arrows between graph vertices, inspired by the Qt diagrams sample app, but I have a problem with render artifacts. When I paint a triangle polygon onto the scene using the following code

```
QPolygonF arrowHead;
... some setup
painter->drawPolygon(arrowHead);
```

and then I move around the vertex to which the triangle (`arrowHead` polygon) was pointing, it does get repainted, but the old triangle still stays rendered on the screen

[image: render error]

Any update on the `scene` fixes the issue however (dragging on the background, or calling `update/invalidate` from another place).

[image: render ok]

The problem is that I don't know where to force the update, or how to tell Qt to invalidate the whole area around the vertex that's being dragged.

I've tried calling `scene()->invalidate()` (also update) from the `itemChange` event on the vertex as it's being dragged, but that causes the whole application to crash, so I assume I'm not allowed to call update from there. I also can't call `update` directly from the `paint` method of the arrow, since that would infinitely recurse in its own `paint` method.

Am I rendering this incorrectly, or do I need to manually update the scene somehow? [Here's a link to the whole rendering source code](https://github.com/darthdeus/graphite-gui/blob/dcfaec1c8599b87fc42a91029571b1eead66f966/gui/edge_graphics_item.cpp#L31-L62), though I guess I'm probably doing some elementary mistake with regards to the painting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the trick:

Add

```
ui->graphicsView->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
```

to your constructor of `MainWindow`.

Use this flag will force `QGraphicsView` to update entire viewport.

Comment: While this works, it's an excessive brute-force approach. You've missed the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're not providing the correct bounding rectangle of your edge item. You derive `EdgeGraphicsItem` from `QGraphicsLineItem`, but you didn't override [`boundingRect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect). Make sure that you follow the documentation, and don't miss calling `prepareGeometryChange` as necessary.